# Use distinct and skip in a query

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I tried running this:

```
db.col.find().skip(5).distinct("field1")
```

But it throws an error.

How to use them together?

I can use aggregation but results are different:

```
db.col.aggregate([{$group:{_id:'$field1'}}, {$skip:3},{$sort:{"field1":1}}])
```

What I want is links in sorted order i.e numbers should come first then capital letters and then small letters.

Comment: Have you tried to read manuals? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/

Comment: Tried your query. Got TypeError: db.col.find().distinct("field1") is not a function in shell

Comment: @u_mudler: Yes I did. Initially I was trying this: db.col.distinct("field1").skip(5) but distinct returns a list instead of cursor so can't use skip on this.

Comment: Ok, really a good question.

Comment: Here's a similar question, but it's done with aggregation framework: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16055868/distinct-command-used-with-skip-and-limit

Comment: The problem is if I use aggregation I get different results as compared to the query using just distinct(without including skip).

Answer (score 1):

Distinct method must be run on COLLECTION not on cursor and returns an array. Read this 
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/
So you can't use skip after distinct.

May be you should use this query
`db.col.aggregate([{$group:{_id:'$field1'}}, {$skip:3},{$sort:{"_id":1}}])` because field `field1` will not exists in result after first clause of grouping.

Also I think you should do sort at first and then skip because in your query you skip 3 unsorted results and then sort them.

(If you provide more information about structure of your documents and what output you want it would be more clearly and I will correct answer properly)