# MongoDB using skip and distinct in a query based on values inside an array

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework

So I have document that is structure like this

```
_id: ObjectId('62bbe17d8fececa06b91873d')
clubName: 'test'
staff:[
 '62bbe47f8fececa06b9187d8'
 '624f4b56ab4f5170570cdba3' //IDS of staff members
]
```

A single staff can be assigned to multiple clubs so what I'm trying to achieve is to get all staff that has been assigned to at least one club and display them on a table on the front end, I followed this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16055868/distinct-command-used-with-skip-and-limit) since distinct and skip can't be used on a single query but it just returned this:

```
[
  { _id: [ '624f5054ab4f5170570cdd16', '624f5054ab4f5170570cdd16' ] }  //staff from club 1,
  { _id: [ '624f5054ab4f5170570cdd16', '624f9194ab4f5170570cded1' ] } //staff from club 2,
  { _id: [ '624f4b56ab4f5170570cdba3' ]} //staff from club 3
]
```

my desired outcome would be like this:

```
[ _id : ['624f5054ab4f5170570cdd16', '624f9194ab4f5170570cded1', '624f4b56ab4f5170570cdba3'] ]
```

here's my query:

```
const query = this.clubModel.aggregate(
      [{ $group: { _id: '$staff' } }, { $skip: 0}, { $limit: 10}],
      (err, results) => {
        console.log(results);
      },
    );
```

the values returned are not distinct at all, is there an operation that can evaluate the value inside an array and make them distinct?

Here's my new query after adding the 'createdAt' field in my document structure:

```
const query = this.clubModel.aggregate([
      { $sort: { createdAt: -1 } },
      {
        $unwind: '$drivers',
      },
      {
        $project: {
          isActive: true,
        },
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: 'null',
          ids: {
            $addToSet: '$drivers',
          },
        },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          _id: 0,
        },
      },
      {
        $skip: skip,
      },
      {
        $limit: limit,
      },
    ]);
```

Comment: How does skip and limit fit into this?

Comment: @CharchitKapoor for pagination purposes

Comment: I get that part but in terms of output,  I meant, should the skip and limit be applied to the array? Is that what is required?

Comment: @CharchitKapoor I intend to apply the skip and limit to the final array with the distinct values. I added a sort to the query so that it will result in consistent queries, what do you think of the implementation, is this error prone?

Comment: Where did you added sort exactly?

Comment: @CharchitKapoor I added a new createdAt field in the document and sorted it before unwind

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the new query you have?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246191/discussion-between-charchit-kapoor-and-jam).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this works for you, first `UNWIND` the staff array, and then group on "_id" as `null` and add `staff` values using `$addToSet`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$staff"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "null",
      "ids": {
        "$addToSet": "$staff"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      
    }
  },
  {
    $skip: 0
  },
  {
    $limit: 10
  }
])
```

Here's the working [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4S9gDx5cKxa).